# Remote conda is not visible to pycharm on remote development using ssh

Tags: ssh, pycharm, remote-development

So, I am trying to set up a remote conda interpreter on Windows Pycharm via SSH. I've installed Miniconda on my profile on the server. I've created an environment in conda. Now, when I connect to the server using SSH, it ti not able to detect conda when I give the path to conda.
[image: The is the error it returns when I click on load environments]